# Does Kendo Grid support cell merge or not?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My Grid has the following structure

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: {
       data: data,
       type: 'json'
       },
       pageable: true,
       columns: [
           { field: "SubServiceTypeName", title: "Sub Type" },
           { field: "PrepaidMonthName", title: "Gói dịch vụ" },
           { field: "DeviceName", title: "Tên thiết bị" },
           { field: "DeviceStatusName", title: "Tình rạng" },
           { field: "IsDeployName", title: "Triển khai" },
           { field: "PriceStatementName", title: "CL giá" }
       ]             
 });
```

Result: [image]

I want to merge rows with same value of column [PrepaidMonthName] (call as "Gói dịch vụ"). I don't know if kendo supports merge cells or not yet?
What I expect:

[image]

Or is there another solution for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for myself by searching and experimenting, here is the answer to my question:
Currently Kendo grid `DOES NOT SUPPORT` Merge cells yet, so I need to use pure JS to do this.
I did the following:

```
       $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: data,
                    type: 'json'
                },
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                    { field: "SubServiceTypeName", title: "Sub Type" },
                    { field: "PrepaidMonthName", title: "Gói dịch vụ" },
                    { field: "DeviceName", title: "Tên thiết bị" },
                    { field: "DeviceStatusName", title: "Tình rạng" },
                    { field: "IsDeployName", title: "Triển khai" },
                    { field: "PriceStatementName", title: "CL giá" },
                ]
            });
          
            const table = document.querySelector('.k-grid-content table');

            let headerCell = null;

            for (let row of table.rows) {

                const firstCell = row.cells[1];

                if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
                    headerCell = firstCell;
                } else {
                    headerCell.rowSpan++;
                    firstCell.remove();
                }
            }
        });
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Now how to sort and still get the same merged cell effect. Sorry I am new to KendoUI grids. :)